# Cannot connect to Parity from browser UI

Tags: dapps, parity, browsers, secure-signer

I am not able to connect to Parity via the browser UI. I have tried multiple times with different tokens generated by running the command `parity signer new-token` on the node where parity is running. But the response in the browser is always the same:

`Unable to make a connection to the Parity Secure API. To update your secure token or to generate a new one, run parity signer new-token and supply the token below`

On the node console, I see the following message, every time with different numbers on the first line. The first number is always less than the second one:

`Received old authentication request. (1486765366 vs 1486765433)
Unauthorized connection to Signer API blocked.`

**Parity version:** `Parity/v1.6.0-nightly-afa1edb-20170125/x86_64-linux-gnu/rustc1.14.0`

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I found this https://github.com/ethcore/parity/wiki/UI-Remote-Access that says that the team's main focus is for the UI to work locally. I am trying to access it remotely, and I just checked that my client machine's time is not in sync with http://time.is which, as the doc says, is required. Have not tested whether fixing this gets rid of the error. Will post if it does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is fixed now. As I mentioned in my comment under my question, the root cause was the big time difference of 1 minute and 7 seconds between my machine and https://time.is. My machine had not been able to connect to our internal time servers due to an internal issue, so had fallen behind. Once the time was sync'ed, I was able to connect via the ui interface.

This is the doc that helped me fix this: https://github.com/ethcore/parity/wiki/UI-Remote-Access

Comment: Ah, well done on solving this.

Answer (score 1):

I've come across this issue before and I've solved it by following these steps:

- Stop Parity
- Rename the `key` file in `Parity/Ethereum/network` to `__key`.
- Start Parity

Comment: Thanks, but I tried that and it didn't work for me. Specifically, I still get the same error messages in browser and on the node. There must be something different in my configuration.

Comment: Hmm, that's interesting. Does Parity create a new `key` file?

Answer (score 1):

You can make open it by starting the node with interface IP parameters:

```
$ parity --dapps-interface <IP> --ui-interface <IP>
```

But make sure you really want this. You could also test the functionality of `--dapps-user` and `--dapps-password` to increase the security.

Comment: Are those command line options equivalent to having sections `[dapps]` and `[ui]` with `interface` and `port` specified for both, in the TOML config file, and then starting the node with `$ parity --config <configfile>`? That is how the node was started.

Comment: Yes that should be equivalent.